# Hide "^L" in magit log buffer

Tags: magit

How can I configure the display in the magit buffer so that "^L^L^L" is rendered as a white space? On other platforms, I'm used to seeing entries separated by whitespaces

[image]

magit 20230924.1834
emacs 28.2

Comment: Weird. Which version of git are you using?

Comment: git version 2.39.2

Comment: Seems this works fine with 20231010.1103

Comment: It sounds like it was a temporary bug in some of the development builds of Magit then, so I suggest we close this question as it's not going to be relevant to people in future.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was a bug in a development version of a package, and has since been fixed.

Comment: This is currently happening to me with `git version 2.42.1`

Comment: See https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/5044.